# Access VBA interacting with Excel, second time get Error 91

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am having issues with this script when run for a second time.
Running the script the first time I have no issues and if I close access and rerun the script I also have no issues but when run within say 10 minutes I get the Error 91 “Object Variable or With block variable not set”

The script seems to get stuck on line the line which formats the spreadsheet on the second run. (`With Selection    .Font.Bold = True`)

Script is :

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function LookInduct()

On Error GoTo Induct_err

Dim ExcelApp As New excel.Application
Dim WorkBook As excel.WorkBook
Dim Linecount As Integer
Dim SaveDetails As String

SaveDetails = "C:\LookToInductReport.xlsx"

If Len(Dir(SaveDetails)) > 0 Then
    Kill SaveDetails
  End If

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "LookToInductReport_04", SaveDetails, True, "LookToInduct"

Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("excel.application")

ExcelApp.Visible = False
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Format the Excel File
'------------------------------------------------------------
Linecount = DCount("[NSN]", "LookToInductReport_04") + 1

Set WorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(SaveDetails, , False)

    WorkBook.Sheets("LookToInduct").Select
    With Selection

    ExcelApp.Range("A1:M1").Select
        With Selection
            .Font.Bold = True '<- error #91 here
            .WrapText = True
            .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
            .Interior.Color = 16764057
            .VerticalAlignment = xlTop 
        End With

    End With

    WorkBook.Save
    WorkBook.Close
    ExcelApp.Close
    ExcelApp.Quit

    Set WorkBook = Nothing
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing


    MsgBox "Report saved"

    Exit Function


Induct_err:

    WorkBook.Save
    WorkBook.Close
    ExcelApp.Quit
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: Please read: [mcve]. Then edit your question with the minimal code that reproduces the problem, and mark the line that raises the error. Thanks.

Comment: Also, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts - you seem to be working with two accounts.

Comment: Code has been culled to show the only area which the issue occurs on the second run which is formatting the spreadsheet.

Comment: If I didn't use the second with selection, how would I then select that specific range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't nest one `With Selection ... End With` inside another `With Selection ... End With`

`Selection` is a property of the Excel application object, so use `With ExcelApp.Selection` instead of just `With Selection`

```vb
'With Selection

ExcelApp.Range("A1:M1").Select
    'With Selection
    With ExcelApp.Selection
        .Font.Bold = True
        .WrapText = True
        .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
        .Interior.Color = 16764057
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop 
    End With

'End With
```

Comment: thank you so much, that worked really well. I had to shift some code around but over all worked really well.

Comment: Would you by chance know how to correct this last piece of code:

        ExcelApp.Range("I2:I28").select
        with ExcelApp.Selection
        .AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I28")
        End With

Produces a 1004 error "Application -Defined or object defined error"

Comment: Is the error at `.AutoFill`?  If so, qualify `Range` because that's another Excel property and Access doesn't know squat about it.  So maybe `ExcelApp.Range`

Comment: thank you again. Yes it is at the .AutoFill   Don't have the answer but at least I know where to look. Appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, worked it out, very easy actually.   Defined a new variant as Excelformula, then just selected the range and added ".formula = ExcelFormula"  works really well now.